# Get Token from web site and pass it back to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, oauth-2.0

I need information about how am I suppose to get a token from an external browser passed to my `WPF` application.

1. The user will click a button on my `WPF` which will launch a chrome browser,
2. then the user will log in,
3. after they logged in, I have to get the `access_token` passed back to my `WPF`.

Something like google authentication, when you sign in to a desktop application using google, you get a new tab on your browser, you sign in and then you return to the web application to find it signed in automatically.
I want to build something like this, if possible!

Answer (score 2):

There is a google sample app online that you can reference for how to do this in WPF.

https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows

Specifically, the WPF app is the one named 'OAuthDesktopApp'.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I appreciate it! I actually did fork it and played with for a bit. The problem is how can I use Http to listen external URL?
` var http = new HttpListener();
            http.Prefixes.Add("https://googleForExample.com/");
            output("Listening..");
            http.Start();
`
The reason is: When the user login to the website, I'll redirect them to a specific endpoint on my website!  So I want to make HTTP listening on that specific endpoint. I hope, my idea is clear!

Comment: Don't use the Http to listen to your external URL, it needs to listen to the URL of the oauth server (in this example, google's oauth server). Once you get an http response, and you have verified that you received a valid authorization code, and then exchanged it for a valid authorization token, THEN you can have the WPF app redirect them to your website by simply calling Process.Start on your website's URL.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to use google to sign in, I want to use my own web site authentication and then get the acess_token from it and pass it back to my wpf application

Comment: You're correct, I did misunderstand you. I think your real question is how to write an oauth server that returns an auth token to a calling client. It might be best to post a new question, after you have shown some code on the server side.  Sorry I can't help much further than that.